# Hide both div and javascript code on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have two Divs apart from my content in my Bootstrap Layout

**a) Social networking bar div**

```
<div id="socialnetwork" class="navbar-text navbar-right visible-md visible-lg">
<span class='st_googleplus_large' displayText='Google +'></span>
<span class='st_plusone_large' displayText='Google +1'></span>
<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_fblike_large fblike-align' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span>
</div>
```

**Associated JS Embed Tag**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
stLight.options(
{publisher: "f1325bca-f8fc-4cec-9e01-02cd5ddd29ed", 
doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false}
);
</script>
```

**b) Disqus Comments Div**

```
<div id="disqus_thread" class="col-lg-10 visible-md visible-lg"></div>
```

Screenshot Example    - http://tinypics.in/image/o
 Jsfiddle code Example - http://jsfiddle.net/betacoder/buC6c/

> **My Aim is to ONLY LOAD this DIV along with there associated JAVASCRIPT if the viewport is for midscreen or largescreen and not on
>   mobile / tablet layout (tohide if mobile/tablet)**

Well the "*visible-md visible-lg*" tags lets me to hide the divs in mobile and tablet layouts.

**But still the javascript is loading in the background and consuming the user bandwith.**

> **How to resolve this , would like to load the JS files associated with them only when Bootstrap layout on medium and large screen or on devices above 990px width.**

Any Quickfix ? Love to hear the response or a near workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Even though the markup is hidden, it is still **delivered** to the browser, just like the JavaScript.  You will not be able to prevent JavaScript from loading using only CSS rules.